# Change plot background color

Tags: javascript, plotly

Looking for advice of how to change the background color of the plotly plot to transparent?

I have looked around the docs, but could not find any reference.

```js
pie_chart = {
  'data': [{
    'labels': ['V0', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4', 'V5', 'V6', 'V7', 'V8', 'V9'],
    'values': [55, 22, 31, 32, 33, 45, 44, 42, 12, 67],
    'type': 'pie',
    'sort': false,
  }],

  'layout': {
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)",
    width: 320,
  }

}

Plotly.newPlot('plot', pie_chart.data, pie_chart.layout);
```

```css
#plot {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="plot"> </div>
```

Comment: Use `paper_bgcolor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)"` in the layout and your issue is resolved I guess!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please use `paper_bgcolor` property of `layout` to make it `transparent`.

> **paper_bgcolor (color):**  
> default: "#fff"  
> Sets the color of paper where
>   the graph is drawn.

From the official documentation, available [here](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-plot_bgcolor)

```js
pie_chart = {
  'data': [{
    'labels': ['V0', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4', 'V5', 'V6', 'V7', 'V8', 'V9'],
    'values': [55, 22, 31, 32, 33, 45, 44, 42, 12, 67],
    'type': 'pie',
    'sort': false,
  }],

  'layout': {
    paper_bgcolor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    width: 320,
  }

}

Plotly.newPlot('plot', pie_chart.data, pie_chart.layout);
```

```css
#plot {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="plot"> </div>
```

Comment: @Idan Changed it

Answer (score 3):

**plot_bgcolor** sets the color of plotting area in-between x and y axes.

**paper_bgcolor** sets the color of paper where the graph is drawn (= outside of axes but inside of parent div).

So for a transparent background **you need to use both** in layout section like this:

```
layout = {
   plot_bgcolor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
   paper_bgcolor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
}
```

Official reference: https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-paper_bgcolor

Answer (score 1):

```js
pie_chart = {
  'data': [{
    'labels': ['V0', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4', 'V5', 'V6', 'V7', 'V8', 'V9'],
    'values': [55, 22, 31, 32, 33, 45, 44, 42, 12, 67],
    'type': 'pie',
    'sort': false,
  }],

  'layout': {
    width: 320,
  }

}

Plotly.newPlot('plot', pie_chart.data, pie_chart.layout);
```

```css
#plot {
  background-color: lightblue !important;
}
.main-svg {
   background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="plot"> </div>
```

Is it What you looking for ? Hope it helps!!

Comment: You know, yes, and no. I have tried that, but stupidly failed. That is OK workaround, but I still wonder if there a better way than `important`

Comment: thing is we have to override the default style settings for that plot. Important keyword is doing the same!

Comment: @Sidhanshu_ There is a plotly property for setting the background color the layout . in layout just give `'layout': {
    width: 320,
bgcolor: "rgb(0,0,0,0)"
  }` and remove the css `.main-svg {
   background-color: transparent !important;
}` also plot css does not require `!important` I guess

Comment: @NarenMurali I tried that. But default were still overriding the given styling for background!

Comment: @Sidhanshu_ My bad, the property is `paper_bgcolor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)"`